# One English noun for a gracious postponement of some required action

Tags: word-request

Is it possible in English to come up with only one noun to fill in the blank below to convey the meaning described in the paragraph?

Landowner firstly insisted that the payment should be made by September 5th, but later he listened to my story and was moved with compassion, so he agreed that the payment could be postponed till December 5th.

So, the landowner gave me (a/an) ______________ for three months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, the landowner [granted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grant) me a **grace period of** three months.

In a private agreement, the grace period could be extended beyond the typical 15 days or one month.

> [What Is a Grace Period?](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/grace_period.asp#toc-what-is-a-grace-period)
> A grace period is a set length of time after the due date during which payment may be made without penalty. A grace period, typically of 15 days, is commonly included in mortgage loan and insurance contracts.
>
> How a Grace Period Works
> **A grace period allows a borrower or insurance customer to delay payment for a short period of time beyond the due date.** During this period no late fees are charged, and the delay cannot result in default or cancellation of the loan or contract.

Source: *Investopedia.com*

The term *[deferment](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deferment)* is also a possibility, it means to delay or postpone something.

> She requested a **six-month deferment** on her loan

Source: *Merriam-Webster*

Comment: Perhaps also *extension* (along the lines of a *deferment*)

Comment: @BruceWayne - Simple and brilliant! Thank you.